# Jmeter - when there are number of threads are running, the variable from JSON extractor is not working sometimes

Tags: json, variables, jmeter, extract

I am now using Jmeter to run the test of APIs.

The situation is that I have a login Api which will return a token inside response. I use a JSON extractor to save the token as a variable. Then, I use the ${token} is the header of other requests.

However, I found that when I was trying to run 40-50 threads, the ${token} in some threads would be empty, and caused a high error rate.

Therefore, may I ask is there any method to solve it and why?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try saving full response from the Login API, most probably your server gets overloaded and cannot return the token and returning some error message instead.

There are following options:

1. If you're running JMeter in [command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) you can amend JMeter's [Results File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) to store the results in XML form and include the response data, add the next lines to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
   jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
   ```

   and when you run your test next time the [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) will contain response bodies for all the requests.
2. Another option is using a Listener like [Simple Data Writer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) configured like:

   [image]

   and when you run the test the `responses.xml` file will contain the response data

Both .jtl results file and responses.xml can be inspected using [View Results Tree listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree)

More information: [How to Save Response Data in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-save-response-data-in-jmeter)

Comment: thanks for responding. but want to ask that I don't have to create a local xml file for option 2, right? just create the listener, and follow your configuration?

Comment: the listener will create the xml file itself

Comment: ok, let me have a try, thanks